# How to modify \part style in memoir

Tags: numbering, memoir, parts

A beginner question: I would like to print `\part` with roman numbers 
as it follows:

> I. Teil

or

> I. rész

Someone could please explain me how to do it?

Comment: The default display of part numbers is uppercase roman numerals. Are you referring to the representation in conjunction with the name? Currently, `memoir` prints `Part I` on a single line, with the title on another.

Comment: I need to change the default display as mentioned above. I want to print something like "I. Teil" on the first line and "BlaBla Title" on the second line. That is: the part number should be in Roman numerals, and the part number – followed by a full stop – should appear before the "part", "Teil" or "rész" wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The localisation is done by using the appropriate language with the `babel` package. Memoir has no hooks for modification of the `\part` code, so you need to do it by redefining it in your preamble:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@part[#1]#2{%
  \M@gettitle{#1}%
  \phantomsection
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}%
      {\protect\partnumberline{\thepart}#1}%
    \mempartinfo{\thepart}{#1}{#2}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \mempartinfo{}{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
  \partmark{#1}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \parskip\z@
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \printpartnum.\ \printpartname \partnamenum % changed order and added . here
     \midpartskip
   \fi
   \printparttitle{#2}\par}%
  \@endpart}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\part{A part title}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Many thanks, that's exactly what I needed :))